# Glib - What is the most easy way to execute a GCallback directly?

Tags: callback, glib

What I currently do:

```
/* FIXME: Actually I just want to call that callback ... no idea how that can be done without using a signal */
/* So I just used some random unused signal for it */
gulong handler_id = g_signal_connect_swapped (window, "direction-changed", (GCallback) mycallback, window);
g_signal_emit_by_name (window,"direction-changed");
g_signal_handler_disconnect (window, handler_id);
```

Works well, but is an ugly hack.

I know it is somehow possible to call my callback by using `g_closure_invoke()` in some way, though so far I did not get that to work.

If it matters, the callback will be filled with a function which looks like that:

```
static void myCallbackMethod (GtkWindow *window);
```

Answer (score 2):

A `GCallback` is just a function pointer of a certain type. You can call the function directly, just like any other C function call.

```
mycallback (window);
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that I already tried that. Gives me a compiler error:  too many arguments to function ‘mycallback’ .. probably I first need to cast the function pointer in some way.

Comment: Ok, I just figured it out .. I need `((void (*)(GtkWindow*))mycallback)(window);` in order to get it to work. Thank you for the hint !  If you like, please edit your answer accordingly. Just thought that there is some more "gtk - ish" way to do it.

Comment: It would be better if you called the function with the right number (and types) of arguments, rather than casting it. Casting function pointers, especially to change the number of arguments, gives unspecified behaviour on some (uncommon) platforms, and means you lose the benefits of the compiler’s type checking. Since you’re making a single static function call, I can’t think of a reason why you wouldn’t pass all the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Now I am confused ...  what extra parameters should I pass ? I only have "window" as single parameter, and I did not cast the function to take any other number of parameters. Maybe you refer to `void (*)` ? That ought to be the return type and the base type itself(a pointer). Possibly `(*)` is not required, i'll check this evening.  What would be your proposal to call the function ? The proposal in your answer just does not work, it gives me a compiler error `error: too many arguments to function ‘mycallback’`, like I told in comment1.

Comment: You’ve given two functions in your comments, `mycallback` and `myCallbackMethod`. What are their prototypes?

Comment: There is only one fuction: `myCallbackMethod`. The prototype is like written in the title. `mycallback` is just a pointer to this function as `GCallback`